# logging in to ableCommerce via commerceBuilder api

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ablecommerce

i am trying to log in and authenticate with able Commerce?
i am using their DLLs (commerceBuilder)

i have tried

```
dim user as new commerceBuilder.users.user
user.username = "ABC"
user.password = "PASS"
user.adress = "www.websider.com"
```

does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

AbleCommerce makes use of ASP.NET Forms Authentication with custom membership provider. First validate the user and then if credentials are passed switch context user and set authentication cookie

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
{
      var user = UserDataSource.LoadForUserName(username);
      AbleContext.Current.User = user;
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, false)
}
```